# Is there a way to update a firestore collection with nested maps

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a flutter app with Firebase as the back end. I would like to update a Firestore document with a map of maps.

My map is:

```
  Map<String, Map> updated = {
     'Alcohol': {'score': 3, 'title': 'None in 8 hours'},
     'Sleep': {'score': 5, 'title': 'None in 5 hours'}
    };
```

and I would like it to appear in the Firestore document as

```
Alcohol 
       score: 3
       title: 'None in 8 hours'
Sleep
       score: 5
       title: 'None in 5 hours'
```

This is how I interact with Firestore

```
  Future updateMap(Map updated) async {
    return await mapsReference.doc('ueEyyfIKnPv9ldlZKJ7S').set({updated});
   }
```

and this is how I call the updateMap function

```
updater.updateMap(updated);
```

This breaks the code. I have tried many versions of it without success.

```
    Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type '_CompactLinkedHashSet<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>' 
 is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' of 'data')
```

Does anyone know how to go about it.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "This breaks the code"?  Please edit the question to explain in more detail what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: Is that an error?

Comment: Yes, that's the error I get when I run it